# Can ffmpeg convert wav audio to mxf audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg and am trying to create separate video and audio mxf files. 
My source file has native frame rate of 29.97 and I am trying to create mxf's with 30fps for both video and audio mxf. I was able to create video mxf but couldn't find a way to make audio mxf. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You might get more help if you showed the command that you used for the video, and what you tried for the audio (and what happened when you tried it).   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: For a MXF with only audio, you need to force the Op-Atom variant `-f mxf_opatom` and audio has to be mono PCM 16 or 24 bit.

Comment: I used the below commands: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a copy -r 30 video.mp4